# Limit orientation support to android app

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I want to support my application to support only Portrait and left Landscape mode of orientation.

If My app is in Portrait mode and user changes orientation to landscape-left,
it should change to landscape mode.
But
If My app started in Portrait mode and user changes orientation to landscape-right, it should not change to landscape mode.

similarly
It should change its mode from left-landscape to portrait.

```
if(screenOrientation == 0){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else if(screenOrientation == 1){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
```

I locked the mode depending on screenOrientation value
but when to unlock rotation. without unlocking it wont change its mode in any rotation.

is anyone have idea about it?

Comment: Without code no one can guide you where you doing wrong.

Comment: i have edited code with some code details i have.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in manifest `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: it will lock the screen orientation forever in landscape mode.
My app will work in 0 and 270 degree rotation only.

Comment: but it will changes layout if i rotate landscape right i.e. 270 degree.
as per my  requirement It should be in previous orientation mode.